# Include html code within a Jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have the following JQUery function

```
 $('button.forward').click(function() {

    });
```

where once the button forward - below is the code for the button -
 is clicked, a modal should appear as such

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Read API before asking questions. : http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Answer (score 2):

Add that HTML code at the end of your page (inside the `body` tag) and add the following to your jQuery:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

See the [Bootstrap JavaScript reference](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-methods) for more details.

Comment: thank you. I have applied the code, but my main concern is that the dialog modal quickly dissapears upoin click, below is code  $('button.forward').click(function() {
    $("#myModal2").modal("show");
 });

Comment: What do you mean by this? Are you saying it flashes up for a second then disappears again?

Comment: yes precisely that exactly what occurs

Comment: Hmm I have no idea what would cause that behaviour...

Comment: thank you. my problem has slightly increased and have reposted it there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28349522/inserting-html-code-within-a-jquery-function

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('button.forward').click(function() {
    $("#myModal").modal("show");
 });
```

Comment: thank you. I have applied the code, but my main concern is that the dialog modal quickly dissapears (flashes up for a second then disappears) upon click, below is code $('button.forward').click(function() { $("#myModal2").modal("show"); })

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button.forward').click(function() {
        $("#modal-body").show();
    });
```

if you want the modal-body to be hidden by default use this code :

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#modal-body").hide();
  $('button.forward').click(function() {
            $("#modal-body").show();
        });
});
</script>
```