# Inserting html code within a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parse-platform

I am trying to insert the following:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalForwardMail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Forward this Mail</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"><center>
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="forwardForm.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Receiver Email Address" name="forwardEmail">
                           <input class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" value={{currentUser.get('fullName')}} name="fullName">
                             <input class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" type="text" name="subject">

<input class="form-control" placeholder="Sender Email Address" value={{currentUser.get('username')}} type="text" name="email">
<br><textarea  class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Notes" name="message" cols="30"></textarea>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form></center>
<h3></h3>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Into:

```
 $('button.forward').click(function() {

 });
```

Below is the entire jquery code:

```
var UploadMessage = Parse.Object.extend("Upload"); 

var querym = new Parse.Query(UploadMessage); 
querym.equalTo("user", currentUser); 
querym.equalTo("Type", "Letter"); 
querym.descending("createdAt");
querym.find({ 
success: function(querym) { 

 //alert("Successfully retrieved " );
    // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
    for (var i = 0; i < querym.length; i++) { 
      var object = querym[i];
      (function($) {
   $('#mail-table').append('<tr class="results-row"><td>' + object.get('Date') + '</td><td>' +  object.get('Subject') + '</td><td>' + object.get('Sender') 
   + '</td></tr><tr class="expandMail"><td colspan="3">' 
   +'<label id="action"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalForwardMail" id="actionButton1"><i class="fa fa-share"></i>&nbsp Forward</button></label> <label id="action"><button class="btn btn-default" id="actionButton2"><i class="fa fa-recycle"></i>&nbsp Delete</button></label> </center><br /><label id="uploadedInfo">' +   object.get('Message') + 
'<br /> </label> <br />   <a href=" '+ object.get('documentURL') +' " target="_blank">  <img height="175" width="120" src="content/scan.png" alt="Image" id="previewThumb" class="img-responsive"></a><br /><a href=" '+ object.get('documentURL') +' " target="_blank"> <button  id="actionButton1" class="downloadButton"> <i class="fa fa-download fa-2x"></i>&nbsp Download</button></a><br />' + '</td></tr>');
})(jQuery);

      //alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('playerName'));
    }
    },
    error: function(error) {
    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
    });
    $(document).on('click' , '.results-row', function () {
  $(this).next('.expandMail').toggle();

   $('button.delete').click(function() {
        $(this).parent().parent().prev().remove();
        $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    });

     $('button.forward').click(function() {
    $("#modalForwardMail").modal("now");
 });
});
```

The reason why I want to do that is because I want to grab `object.get('documentURL')` from the jquery function and insert it into the form so the end result looks like this:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalForwardMail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Forward this Mail</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body"><center>
<form name="contactform" method="post" action="forwardForm.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Receiver Email Address" name="forwardEmail">
                           <input class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" value={{currentUser.get('fullName')}} name="fullName">
                             <input class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" type="text" name="subject">

<input class="form-control" placeholder="Sender Email Address" value={{currentUser.get('username')}} type="text" name="email">
<br><textarea  class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Notes" name="message" cols="30"></textarea>
object.get('documentURL')
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form></center>
<h3></h3>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: 404 error question not found?

Comment: Sure i can clarify. I want to include object.get('documentURL') in a section into my form . object.get is defined within the javascript function and i need to reference it within html. Essentially this form is a message form where user can forward the message to another and in it a file would be included

Comment: why dont you just create a <div> and set url in <div> through jquery check http://jsfiddle.net/singhakash07/7pm2ruvq/

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. Based your example, could I do something like this  $('button.forward').click(function() {
    $("#modalForwardMail").modal("now");
   $("#url").object.get('documentURL');
 }); ? where in the html its <div id="url"></div> instead

Comment: i dint get you explain properly what you want to achieve

Comment: sorry let me elaborate more. My initial question started as this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28254670/include-html-code-within-a-jquery-function but then it extended to the current. essentiaally i want to include this object.get('documentURL') into form. What happens here is that once user has viewed their message, they are able to forward it, and in the forward form (this one),a link to the file included in the message is displayed

Comment: if my solution answered your question then consider accepting it so other having same problem would know the question is answered

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood you want to show form in a modal onclick of Forward link.So here is the code

**html**

```
   <a data-toggle="modal" href="http://fiddle.jshell.net/bHmRB/51/show/" data-target="#myModal" id="getModal">Forward</a>


    <div class="modal fade" id="modalForwardMail" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Forward this Mail</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body"><center>
    <form name="contactform" method="post" action="forwardForm.php" class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Receiver Email Address" name="forwardEmail">
                               <input class="form-control" placeholder="Full Name" type="text" value={{currentUser.get('fullName')}} name="fullName">
                                 <input class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" type="text" name="subject">

    <input class="form-control" placeholder="Sender Email Address" value={{currentUser.get('username')}} type="text" name="email">
    <br><textarea  class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Notes" name="message" cols="30"></textarea>
        <div id="url"></div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form></center>
    <h3></h3>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
       $('#getModal').click(function() {
            var pageURL = $(location).attr("href");
             $("#url").text(pageURL);
             $("#modalForwardMail").modal("toggle");
           // alert(pageURL);

            });

    });
```

#### DEMO1

with **document.Url** as you specified in comments below.


#### DEMO2

Comment: thank you for your response, and I truly appreciate all of your effort. I guess I should of clarified a bit.  this line    $("#url").text(pageURL); is retrieve the page url, what I want it to retreive and insert in the modal is object.get('documentURL')  the documentURL is a not a page a url, its an aribtrary url generated from google drive, and retrieved from parse. In a nutshell, this exact line  object.get('documentURL')  needs to be inserted into the modal box as it will retrieve the url

Comment: @Jon i dint heard of it have you used it somewhere then do let me know.I have edited my answer with document.URL demo and its giving the same url(as it is supposed to) I think you misunderstood somethig. And also `for what purpose you want this url in form ?`